# dynamic updation of images on an html page on selection of a particular choice of radio button

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html

If I assign a "value" to a radio button to use that "value" in my script programming and suppose that value is assigned to a image and the code looks like this

```
<input type="radio" name="image" value="500"/><img src="1.png">
<input type="radio" name="image" value="500"/><img src="2.png">
<input type="radio" name="image" value="500"/><img src="2.png">
```

How can I identify which image is which?

I want to identify that user has selected which image, but my constraint is this that the value for all images will be the same.. and since it is a radio so name will be same for all in a same radio group.. what else??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an id to each input item. Then check using `document.getElementById("radio1").checked`

```
<input type="radio" id = "radio1" name="image" value="500"/><img src="1.png">
<input type="radio" id = "radio2" name="image" value="500"/><img src="2.png">
<input type="radio" id = "radio3" name="image" value="500"/><img src="2.png">

function check()
{
   for (var i=1; i <= 3; i++)
   {
     if (document.getElementById("radio" + i).checked)
         alert("image is " + i + ".png");
   }
}
```

Comment: yeah that will work.. thanks a lot. why dont i think that earlier??

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="image" value="500"   onchange="fnc(this.id)"/><img src="1.png" >
<input type="radio" id="2" name="image" value="500"  onchange="fnc(this.id)"/><img src="2.png" >
<input type="radio"  id="3" name="image" value="500"  onchange="fnc(this.id)"/><img src="2.png">

<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc(myid)
{
    if(myid=='1')
    {
        alert("you've selected image"+myid);
    }
    else if(myid=='2')
    {
        alert("you've selected image"+myid);
    }
    else if(myid=='3')
    {
        alert("you've selected image"+myid);
    }
}
</script>
```